# configuring spring-security and spring-mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to configure my spring-security project for first time but when I try to login I receive a message: "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". May be somewhere under the hood it redirects to admin again, but where? 
here is my spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security

     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true" >
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('Admin')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login login-page='/login' login-processing-url="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />

    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccessful" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
                           users-by-username-query= "select login, password, 'true' from employee where login=?"
                           authorities-by-username-query= "select login, role from employee where login =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:import resource="data-source-cfg.xml"/>
</beans:beans>
```

controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAdmin(ModelMap model) {
        return "admin";
    }   


    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String enter(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, ModelMap model){
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }
...
```

Table with user's login and role looks like:

```
Employee
|id|login   |password   |first_name|last_name|mobile_phone|role   |
|1 |login1  |password1  |name1     |lname1   |phone1      |User   |
|2 |login2  |password2  |name2     |lname2   |phone2      |Admin  |
```

spring security version is 4.0.3. 
This is my first experience with spring-mvc and spring-security so the question may be noobie. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are simply redirecting to the admin page on the /login resource, which is where it will send people if they are not logged in. Since /admin requires a specific role, it will try to go to the login page if the user is not logged in which you have redirecting back to the admin page, thus creating a loop.

You want to return a view and not redirect back to the admin page.